# Calling second activity with startActivity causing crash

Tags: android, android-activity

This seems to be a common problem, but the solutions available have not solved my specific situation.  I've added a second activity that I call from the first with the following code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, timerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("tmrPredTime", PredTime);
            startActivity(intent);
        return true;
```

Here is my android manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".timerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_timer" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

On "startActivity(intent)", the app crashes with the following logcat output.

```
    03-24 15:58:43.825    7005-7005/com.byu.iainhunter.iku E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.byu.iainhunter.iku, PID: 7005
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.byu.iainhunter.iku/com.byu.iainhunter.iku.timerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2081)
        at com.byu.iainhunter.iku.timerActivity.<init>(timerActivity.java:16)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

timerActivity code

```
    package com.byu.iainhunter.iku;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    public class timerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
//final TextView tbTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
//final Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

    double PredTime = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("tmrPredTime", 0);
    System.out.println("PredTime: " + PredTime);


    //buttonStart.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    //    @Override
    //    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //        tbTest.setText("Your Text");
    //        return true;
    //    }
    //});
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_timer, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Show the code of `timerActivity`, there is the problem. From the log it seems that you are calling `findViewById()` in the constructor, you can't do that.

Comment: I can't fit all the code of timerActivity in a comment, but I am using findViewById() in there.  I'll mess with that and see what I get.

Comment: When I removed the findViewById line in timerActivity everything was fine, but I need to declare a button for usage in timerActivity.  How to I declare it?  I had used: final Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

Comment: @user2428818 You can update your question with `timerActivity`'s code.

Comment: You confuse constructor with `onCreate()` method. You have to use the latter for activities.

Comment: I just added the timerActivity code.  So, I need to change the onCreate() line?

Comment: first of all ... to make debugging easier .... don't pass anything and don't receive anything .... just start a new activity from older activity.... if that  successful then pass something ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've committed a cardinal sin here of posting code which does not match your error message!   You solved your problem by commenting out the bare findViewById() lines, and thus posted code which no longer causes your error.  To actually fix your problem, move those inside your onCreate() method.

```
/* Declare them here, but don't attempt to lookup, as that is
   not legal until onCreate() is called */

TextView tbTest;
Button buttonStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

    /* only once onCreate() has been called do you have
       a fully initialized Activity instance in which
       it is legal to call methods like findViewById() */

    tbTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);


    double PredTime = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("tmrPredTime", 0);
    System.out.println("PredTime: " + PredTime);
```

Comment: That took care of all my troubles.  Thank you for your help.